# Check if function passed as argument to class __init__ returns right type

Tags: python, numpy, class

I am trying to set up a class to generalize some numerical simulations, the core of the problem is the following:

Imagine I have a function that returns a `numpy.ndarray` type, like

```
def new_fun():
    return numpy.zeros((2,2,2,2))
```

and then I have a class declaration like:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self,function):
        self.function  = function
```

**My Goal:** I would like to check upon class initialization if the argument passed to `__init__` is a function and returns the right type, for instance something like:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self,function):
        if type(function) is types.FunctionType:
        #from here is pseudocode
           if return_type(function) is numpy.ndarray:
              self.function  = function
```

**Important is:** given the type of application,the passed function must not be executed to get information about is return type, it could take a while.

Comment: How can you get the return type _without_ executing it, given  that you don't know what type it'll return until it's done so?

Comment: Consider using type hints and a tool like `mypy`

Comment: @Barmar,i will look into it thanks, type hints looks like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it's [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable)

```py
def __init__(self, fn):
    assert callable(fn)
```

It's not practical to know what some functions will return, but you can use type hints around this

```py
from typing import Callable
...

    def __init__(self, fn: Callable[[None], numpy.ndarray]):
        if not callable(fn):
            raise TypeError("expected a callable function, but got {type(fn)}")
```

A great benefit of Python is that it's easy to read and write - in most cases, it's not practical or helpful to *prevent* users from misusing your API, but you should strive to *help them use it properly* with a good docstring, comments, and type hinting